# Finding unique occurences of values in array of Class Objects

Tags: c++, string, methods, unique, counter

**UPDATED**

I have a Class Object array that can hold up to 50 objects defined by this class...

```
class Visitors{
    public:
    string IP;
    string URL;
string dateAccessed;
};
```

So I have this array of these and each value is already taken care of and initialized properly. But I want to count the number of unique IPs that went to their corresponding URL between 2 dates.

```
int getUniques(Visitors info[], string url, string startDate, string endDate){
    int count = 0;
    string temp;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++) {
        if (url == info[i].URL && dateChecker(startDate, endDate, info[i].dateAccessed)) {
            if (temp.empty()) {
                temp = info[i].IP;
                cout << "I'm first temp " << temp << endl;
                cout << "First IP " << info[i].IP << endl;
                count++;
            }
            if (!temp.empty() && temp != info[i].IP) {
                cout << "I'm the rest of temp " << temp << endl;
                cout << "I'm the rest " << info[i].IP << endl;
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

So, I have everything sorted out except one problem. I can't properly check the unique with this algorithm. I set it so when my temp string is empty I set the first found IP to that temp and check all others against. The issue I run into is, lets say IPs are a value between 1 and 5. If the first IP that goes into temp is 1, the second and third IP could be 2 and then 2 again. Obviously 2 isn't different than 2 but it is different from 1, thus allowing the counter to increment.

How could I make this work the way I intend?

Comment: For starters, don't use string dates. As your date info is read, construct real date/time values using the [standard library date/time functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c), then use those for comparisons and/or differencing.

Comment: Could you elaborate? My dates are strings that look like this "MM/DD/YYYY." Is there a way to convert it into some form of actual time variable?